# TYPO3 Frontend Login: URL won't be accepted if not logged in

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript, typo3-10.x

I want to login with the right URL, but after entering this URL, it changes automatically to the start page.

**Example 1 (works, because I'm login):**
I'm logged in as TYPO3 frontend user. I have the URL *mywebsite/index.php?id=22* and put it in the browser. I got the right site mywebsite/index.php?id=22.

**Example 2 (doesn't, because I'm not logged in):**
I'm not logged in to the system and try to enter the URL *mywebsite/index.php?id=22*. After the go (enter) the URL switched to the start page (login page) mywebsite/index.php?id=1

Is it possible to get to the right site, if I'm not logged in to the system? I want the enter of the URL, then the login screen and after the login, I want to get to my URL.

What do I need to do, in the backend? It is TYPO3 Version 10

Comment: Under TYPO3 9 and 10 you can do a lot of error handling in the Configuration backend module. 
See  https://docs.typo3.org/p/aaw-team/pagenotfoundhandling/3.0/en-us/Configuration/Site/Index.html

Comment: EXT:felogin can handle redirects back to an access-restricted page. Have a look at the referrer mode (https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-felogin/master/en-us//LoginMechanism/RedirectModes/Index.html#defined-by-referrer)

Comment: @JulianHofmann: make it an answer instead just a comment

Answer (score 0):

The Frontend Login (EXT:felogin) can handle redirects back to an access-restricted page.

Have a look at the Redirect Modes especially the referrer mode in the [Extension Documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-felogin/master/en-us//LoginMechanism/RedirectModes/Index.html#defined-by-referrer)